# UnboundLocalError - referenced before assignment

Tags: python

first I'd like to say that I understand what this exception means what I can't figure is how can it happen in my code.

```
def wrapfunction(...):
    ...
    try:
        ...
            pages = [i for i in range(0, num_of_pages)]
            datarALL = []
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_of_workers) as executor:
                futh = [(executor.submit(self.getdata, page, data, ...)) for page in pages]
                for data in as_completed(futh):
                    datarALL.extend(data.result())
            print ("Finished generateing data.")
            ...
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Wrap function exception")
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        print (str(e))
```

and the function `getdata` is:

```
def getdata(self, page, data, ...):
    tries = 10
    for n in range(tries):
        try:
            ...
            url = 'http://...'
            responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=self.hed, verify=False)
            responsedata.raise_for_status()
            if responsedata.status_code == 200:  # 200 for successful call
                responsedata = responsedata.text
                jsondata = json.loads(responsedata)
                if "results" in jsondata:
                    if jsondata["results"]:
                        datarALL.extend(jsondata["results"])
                        break   
        except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, ConnectionResetError) as e:
            print ("page #{0} run #{1} failed. Returned status code {2}. Reason: {3}. Msg: {4}. Retry.".format(page, n, responsedata.status_code, responsedata.reason, sys.exc_info()[0]))
            if n == tries - 1:
                print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
                os._exit(1)  #One thread max retried - close all threads and exit the process.
    print ("{2} page {0} finished. Length is {1}".format(page,len(datarALL),str(datetime.now())))
    return datarALL
```

What I see on console is:

```
2018-09-05 15:27:40.938418 page 84 finished. Length is 249
2018-09-05 15:27:42.511234 page 86 finished. Length is 249
2018-09-05 15:27:44.080980 page 85 finished. Length is 249
2018-09-05 15:27:54.925693 page 88 finished. Length is 217
Wrap function exception
Unexpected error: <class 'UnboundLocalError'>
local variable 'responsedata' referenced before assignment
```

Now, I get that the exception is on the wrap function because I don't catch it on `getdata` but I don't understand why `getdata` generate this exception in the first place. `Page 88` is the last page so all pages returned with data - I checked that all appear. note that it also calculated the length so How could it calculated the length if there was a reference before assignment?

My log

Comment: If you don't catch the exception, you will see the full stack trace, which will be more useful than your prints

Comment: @zvone What I posted is what I see It's a copy from the console. I didn't edit it.. Maybe my print command in the exception can be changed to print more details?

Comment: You can simply remove the whole `except`, or replace the prints with a simple `raise`

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace is not available, so I have to guess, but it seems to be the line in the exception handler which uses `responsedata`:

```
print ("page #{0} run #{1} failed. Returned status code {2}. Reason: {3}. Msg: {4}. Retry.".format(page, n, responsedata.status_code, responsedata.reason, sys.exc_info()[0]))
```

That is going to fail of the exception was raised before the assignment to `responsedata` was made.

You should never use within `except` block the variables which you initialize within the `try` block, because they don't have to be available there.

BTW,  I suggest not using lines which are that long.

Comment: That could be it but responsedata.raise_for_status() suppose to address this.

Comment: How is it possible that exception happened before assignment but the page was still retrieved and processed?

Comment: You are assuming too much. I would not be so sure that it was processed. Maybe the next one raised the exception.

Comment: responsedata.raise_for_status()   updates responsedata.status_code, responsedata.reason. They can't be empty... This is the whole idea behind the request package isn't it?

Comment: Anyway, you should never ever use within `except` block the variables which you initialize within the `try` block, because they don't have to be available there

Comment: I will change it to                 `if all([responsedata ,responsedata.status_code,responsedata.reason]): 
                    print ("page #{0} run #{1} failed. Returned status code {2}. Reason: {3}. Msg: {4}. Retry.".format(page, n, responsedata.status_code, responsedata.reason, sys.exc_info()[0]))
                else:
                    print ("page #{0} run #{1} failed. Msg: {2}. Retry.".format(page, n, sys.exc_info()[0]))`  will that be better?

Comment: No, you cannot use the variable if it is not initialized. Not even to do `if var`

Comment: You can, for example, use multiple try/except blocks to handle different problems

Comment: how I do that in this case?